# Add link to view data if no matching record

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that shows taxonomy terms with a relationship to show nodes that have a term reference to that term (relationship not required, aka LEFT JOIN).

For terms that don't have a matching node I would like to show an "add content" link.

The usual "no results" behavior doesn't seem work in this situation. What's the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) to the rescue:

```
<?php
if (is_null($row->nid)){
    print '<a href=node/add/mytype?edit[field_mytype][und]='.$row->tid.'>add node for this term</a>';
}
?>
```

I can even pass the tid through the URL and have it prepopulated on the form (using [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate)).